# How do I get to know that a JSON string contains an array without any key provided (in Java)?

Tags: json, gson

Json Code Below:

```json
{
  "supplierName": null,
  "materialNumber": "TEST_MATERIAL_NUMBER",
  "drugList": {
    "data": [{
      "drugId": "11",
      "drugName": "TEST_MATERIAL_NUMBER_1",
      "drugPzn": "TEST_PZN_1"
    }, {
      "drugId": "12",
      "drugName": "TEST_MATERIAL_NUMBER_2",
      "drugPzn": "TEST_PZN_2"
    }],
    "recordCount": 2
  }
}
```

Comment: Iterate over all elements and check if their type is array?

Comment: @maio290 could you pls write java code ? faced issues.By default all json object have type "Object".

Comment: @maio290
or simply how to know if a json object is of type array in java